# How does the compiler know the name of captured variables in an std::function?

Tags: c++

Something surprised me, and that was that if I assign a capturing lambda (syntactic sugar for a constructed object with an overloaded function call operator) to an std::function during debug at runtime the compiler tells me the names of the members of that functor/class:

```
std::function<void()> callable1;
std::function<void()> callable2;
std::function<void()> callable3;


int main()
{
    int aa = 1;
    int bb = 1;

    callable1 = [dog = aa, cat = bb]() {
        return 5;
    };
    callable2 = [kitchen = aa, lounge = bb]() {
        return 5;
    };
    callable3 = [hammer = aa, sickle = bb]() {
        return 5;
    };



    std::vector < std::function<void()>> callables;
    callables.push_back(callable1);
    callables.push_back(callable2);
    callables.push_back(callable3);
}
```

And what I see on the compiler is:

[image]

That's very impressive, I'm wondering how it's done. Whatever technique is being used I'm guessing is a very method of reflection I would love to learn about because c++ doesn't have reflection features. The funny thing is that the size of an std::function is 64 bytes on my machine whether is debug or release mode, so I don't know how they're storing the strings as names of the members.

Comment: I think you mean the debugger. The compiler does not do anything at runtime anymore

Comment: What led you to think that this has anything to do with reflection? How is this different from having any other class with members named `dog` and `kitchen`, that a debugger will happily show you without the benefit of reflection?

Comment: The captures are stored in a lambda object not in the function itself. It looks like the debug visualizer can make a distinction on the callable associated with the function and show the lambda members

Comment: I do not know how the debug does this in detail, but it's not fundamentally different from how it does it for any type. 
std::function is erasing the type, but internally there's (most probably, depends on implementation) a heap allocated object that knows the type.

Comment: Debug info has a "type name -> list of members" global map somewhere, and `std::function` stores `std::type_index` which is used as a key into this map.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Because it does type erasure. At runtime I can switch the type held by the std::function. Normally the debugger shows you static types.

Comment: Yes, it is type erasure ***for you***. But your debugger has access to all the private and internal members of a particular `std::function` template instance, and can dig down to the underlying objects that are hidden away, deep inside their innards, and simply show you what they are.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So std::function stores type_index in the class? How can I get this information? I mean the string names and offsets, etc?

Comment: `how it's done` That's very broad, with many, many layers. Compiler stores debugging information, debugger reads them. If the std::function points to a lambda that debugger has debugging information for, debugger will try to use it. `How can I get this information? I mean the string names and offsets, etc?` a short overfly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF . The simplest is, you can access it using the debugger.

Comment: [`std::function::target_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target_type). This only gives you the type. The member information is somewhere in the debug info, you'll have to parse it to know.

Comment: Basically this is template magic. [Here is nice basic explenation](https://youtu.be/xJSKk_q25oQ).

Answer (score 1):

> How does the compiler know the name of captured variables in an std::function?

On Linux, `gcc -g` will add additional sections to the [ELF executable](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

```
$ readelf -S ./a.out | grep debug
  [29] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000561c
  [30] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00005aec
  [31] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000cf7e
  [32] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000da6c
  [33] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000ed66
  [34] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0001499c
```

These sections contain debugging information in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format about the program. For example in `.debug_str` there are strings referenced by debugging information in `.debug_info`:

```
$ readelf -x .debug_str ./a.out  | grep kitchen
  0x00005ae0 656e005f 5f6b6974 6368656e 005f5f73 en.__kitchen.__s
$ readelf -x .debug_str ./a.out  | grep dog
  0x00004170 5f646f67 005f5a4e 53743676 6563746f _dog._ZNSt6vecto
$ readelf -x .debug_str ./a.out  | grep sickle
  0x000042a0 64005f5f 7369636b 6c650077 6373746f d.__sickle.wcsto
```

Debugger inspects the `std::function`, finds a function pointer. Then scans all entries inside `.debug_info` about debugging information associated with that pointer. Then parses that information and displays parsed results in your IDE.

> How can I get this information? I mean the string names and offsets, etc?

Usually and most commonly, you access that information *with the debugger*.  It is the tool to access that information. You can use [libdwarf](https://www.prevanders.net/dwarf.html) and [efitools](http://sourceware.org/elfutils/) to access that information from your own programs.

For example, you can include ELF library in your program and `open(argv[0])` and then parse the debugging sections in your own ELF executable and display information about it. Typically, inspecting ELF itself is used when displaying nice stack traces on C++ exceptions.

Comment: the debugger in this case is Visual Studio, based on the screen shot